# Modular aritmetic and fields

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm studying the concept of field applied to modular aritmetic.
Is it correct to say that, if the dimension is a prime number $p$ then field properties are satisfied for the integers $\bmod p$ ?
And that, if the dimension is a power of a prime number $p$ (that is $p^{n}$), not all integers $\bmod p^{n}$ form a field, but only a set of $p^{n}$ integers ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The integers modulo $p$ for a prime $p$ does form a field.

The integers modulo $p^n$ for $n>1$ doesn't form a field. And there isn't a subset of that which forms a field either.

There are fields with $p^n$ elements for any prime $p$ and natural number $n$. However, for $n>1$ this field does not coincide with the ring of integers modulo $p^n$. For instance, the additive group of such a field is $(\Bbb Z_p)^n$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I would like to study your assertions on a book or websites, do you have some links?

Comment: @AleQuercia Any introductory book in abstract algebra (as long as it covers fields at all) should do.

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: However, take a look at Theorem 4.1 [here](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/Maths/Courseware/NumberTheory/ch04.pdf)

Comment: @AleQuercia That seems to agree with me: The integers modulo $p$ is a field iff $p$ is prime. That's what theorem 4.1 says too.

Comment: Yes yes, you're right :)

Comment: What means that for a prime $p$ and $n>1$ there exists only one field with order $p^{n}$ ? Isn't obvious that there exist only one field ?

Comment: @AleQuercia First of all, it should say "There is only one field _up to isomorphism_" (there are different fields, but they are isomorphic). Second, no, it's [not at all obvious](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544557/finite-fields-of-the-same-order-are-isomorphic) that all fields of order $27$ are isomorphic. Or that all fields of order $625$ are. And so on. But they _are_ isomorphic, and that's what that statement means.

Comment: If there are different fields, in what are different ?

Comment: @AleQuercia When two things are different, but isomorphic, the only difference between them is basically the names of the elements. For instance, you can have the field with elements $\{0, 1, a, a+1\}$, where $x + x = 0$ for any $x$, and $a\cdot a = a+1$. This would be a field with $4$ elements. You can also have a field with elements $\{p, q, r, p+q\}$ with the rules that for any $x$ in the field, $x + r = x$, $x + x = r$ and $p\cdot x = x$, while $q^2 = p + q$. This is also a field of $4$ elements. They are not the same field. But they are isomorphic.

Comment: Is it correct to say that if we consider the field with order $p^{n}$ , where p is prime , then the element $p^{n}$  doesn't belong to the field since its inverse doesn't exist ?

Comment: @AleQuercia What do you mean by "the element $p^n$"? And what do you mean by "exist"? If you add $1$ to itself $p$ times in such a field, then that gives you $0$. So in a sense $p = 0$. And you can raise $0$ to the $n$th power no problem. Inverses aren't requied for powitive exponents to make sense.